# Slideshow Fix and Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I found out how to create a slideshow from a w3Schools. The slideshow is currently manual, meaning the user must click to change to another slide.

**I would like to make it so the user can manually click or wait for the timer. Every, let's say 5 seconds, the slideshow will change slide.**

I also need to fix an issue which isn't shown on the JsFiddle. **When the page is loaded, all 3 images in the slideshow are loaded**, when the user clicks the arrow to change slide they return to just showing one which it should upon loading. I'm not sure why this happens but I can't fix it.

So the following will be loaded upon page load

```
<img src="images/home/(myimagehere).png>
<img src="images/home/(myimagehere2).png>
<img src="images/home/(myimagehere3).png>
```

Rather than just one, after clicking the arrow only one displays, it essentially fixes its self.

I am also open to other slideshow methods, this is just one I found which worked somewhat.

https://jsfiddle.net/a4zxrLem/

**Important: In JsFiddle example the arrows do not change the image, however they do work.**

Comment: What you're looking for is the window.setInterval method. Simply call window.setInterval(function(){}, 1000) and pass in a function as the first argument, and the number of milliseconds you'd like as an interval as the second argument. This will call the function you pass in ever x number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
setInterval(function(){
   plusSlides(1);
}, 5000);//for 5 seconds
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/a4zxrLem/2/

Your second problem is simpler: for the fiddle to work, select "**Load Type**: No wrap in body", on the menu that shows up when you click "javascript".